# Orthogonal vectors in 4D

Tags: geometry, vectors, rotations, 4-manifolds

Consider two 4D vectors: $v_1=(\cos\varphi_1\sin\theta_1\sin\psi_1,\sin\varphi_1\sin\theta_1\sin\psi_1,\cos\theta_1\sin\psi_1,\cos\psi_1)$ and $v_2$, this vectors are orthogonal $v_1 \cdot v_2=0$, I guess that I can express $v_2(\varphi_1,\theta_1,\psi_1,\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha, \; \beta$ are angles, which define rotations around $v_1$. How can I do this?

For 3D it's a simple task: I find some orthogonal to $v_1$ vector and rotate it around $v_1$ by $R(\alpha)$ matrix. But in 4D, rotaions around vector don't define and I don't understand how can I costruct this two-parametric ($\alpha, \beta$) manifold.

Comment: $v_2=(-\sin\varphi_1\sin\theta_1\sin\psi_1,\cos\varphi_1\sin\theta_1\sin\psi_1,0,0)$ is obviously orthogonal to $v_1$ and there are many others.

Comment: Yeah, it's true, but i want to find full manifold of $v_2$ vectors and parametrize them by two angles $\alpha, \beta$